# CakePhp : Cake bake doesn't work on Ubuntu. (PDOException)

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, cakephp, cake-bake

I'm trying to run Cake Bake on Ubuntu.
To be clear :

- The Environment, Filesystem, Database and the DebugKit are Ok as it is mentioned on the first page generated by CakePhp.
- The "bin/cake bake" shows this message :

```
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_intl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_intl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

    Welcome to CakePHP v3.4.5 Console
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    App : src
    Path: /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/src/
    PHP : 7.0.18-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    The following commands can be used to generate skeleton code for your application.

    Available bake commands:

    - all
    - behavior
    - cell
    - component
    - controller
    - fixture
    - form
    - helper
    - mailer
    - migration
    - migration_diff
    - migration_snapshot
    - model
    - plugin
    - seed
    - shell
    - shell_helper
    - task
    - template
    - test

    By using `cake bake [name]` you can invoke a specific bake task.
```

- Everytime I run 'bin/cake bake model questions' or 'bin/cake bake all' I get this output :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_intl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_intl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Welcome to CakePHP v3.4.5 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : src
Path: /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/src/
PHP : 7.0.18-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
---------------------------------------------------------------
One moment while associations are detected.
Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in [/opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver/PDODriverTrait.php, line 47]
2017-05-07 14:24:47 Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver/PDODriverTrait.php on line 47
Stack Trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver/PDODriverTrait.php(47): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '', Array)
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver/Mysql.php(104): Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql->_connect('mysql:host=loca...', Array)
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Schema/BaseSchema.php(45): Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql->connect()
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Dialect/MysqlDialectTrait.php(63): Cake\Database\Schema\BaseSchema->__construct(Object(Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql))
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Schema/Collection.php(52): Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql->schemaDialect()
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Schema/CachedCollection.php(42): Cake\Database\Schema\Collection->__construct(Object(Cake\Database\Connection))
#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Connection.php(367): Cake\Database\Schema\CachedCollection->__construct(Object(Cake\Database\Connection), true)
#7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Connection.php(386): Cake\Database\Connection->getSchemaCollection()
#8 /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php(959): Cake\Database\Connection->schemaCollection()
#9 /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php(911): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->_getAllTables()
#10 /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php(207): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->listAll()
#11 /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php(127): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->getAssociations(Object(Cake\ORM\Table))
#12 /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php(110): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->getTableContext(Object(Cake\ORM\Table), 'answers', 'Answers')
#13 /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php(97): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->bake('Answers')
#14 /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/Shell.php(472): Bake\Shell\Task\ModelTask->main('answers')
#15 /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/Shell.php(465): Cake\Console\Shell->runCommand(Array, false, Array)
#16 /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(230): Cake\Console\Shell->runCommand(Array, true, Array)
#17 /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(182): Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher->_dispatch(Array)
#18 /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(128): Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher->dispatch(Array)
#19 /opt/lampp/htdocs/quizz/bin/cake.php(34): Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#20 {main}
```

- The Cake Bake run when I put 'bin/cake bake controller questions'.

I didn't figure out what's the problem after passing hours trying to solve it. I have been using cake bake on windows and I never find such difficulty to run cake bake.
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Looks like you may have pasted some config bits from your windows config file to your Ubuntu one. `php_intl.dll` and `php_mbstring.dll` should be `php_intl.so` and `php_mbstring.so`.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Don't know how to fix this

Comment: @AlexHowansky I just fixed it. I commit a mistake when I modified the php.ini in 'etc/php/7.0/cli'. I reset the file and enable intl_php and mbstring in 'etc/php/7.0/apache2'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally ....
Just replace localhost by 127.0.0.1

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        /**
         * CakePHP will use the default DB port based on the driver selected
         * MySQL on MAMP uses port 8889, MAMP users will want to uncomment
         * the following line and set the port accordingly
         */
        //'port' => 'non_standard_port_number',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'quizz_db',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'flags' => [],
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'log' => false,
```

By :

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        /**
         * CakePHP will use the default DB port based on the driver selected
         * MySQL on MAMP uses port 8889, MAMP users will want to uncomment
         * the following line and set the port accordingly
         */
        //'port' => 'non_standard_port_number',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'quizz_db',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'flags' => [],
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'log' => false,
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked when I changed
'host' => '127.0.0.1', in app.default.php default dataresources
and in app.php

I hope it'll help

Thanks